# Display Image on hover for items in a bullet list

Tags: media, theming

Using Drupal 7 and I'd like to do the following, have 2 columns, one with bulleted text and the second with an image.

I'd like the image in the second column to change when the user hovers over the bulleted text in the first column.

How hard would this be? Is there an existing Drupal module to accomplish this?